# Which design patterns should I investigate for translating models?

Tags: design-patterns

I am writing a program that reads data from `Model A` into another `Model B`, and vice versa. For example, let's say model A contains class Cat, and model B contains class Kitty. Cat is roughly equivalent to Kitty, but there is some translation required. My code will need to do that translation.

A caller of my code should be able to invoke something like, `mycode.push(cat)`, or Cat `cat = mycode.pull()`;

What design patterns are recommended for this scenario?

Comment: This isn't the correct site for a question about design patterns.  Try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Bridge pattern will be good here